# What object property contains the Route Name being used when inside ControllerBase

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

How do I find the Route Name that is being used when inside of the ControllerBase using it?

For example, I have a route like this:

```
routes.MapRoute("Search", "{controller}.mvc/{action}/{criterion}", new { controller = "", action = "", criterion = "" });
```

...and in my ControllerBase I need the Object.Property that contains "Search" or the name of the Route that the ControllerBase is currently using if not search.

Thank you.

-Jessy Houle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question has come up a number of times in various forms. The short answer is that you can't - the Route name is not stored anywhere in the routing data.

There have been various workarounds proposed for this.  [See this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/363211/how-can-i-get-the-route-name-in-controller-in-asp-net-mvc) for some code for one implementation of Route name tracking.  There are others around as well.

Comment: Is there any way that you can think of to re-create the URL with one changed value such as this:

UrlHelper u = new UrlHelper(Url.RequestContext, Url.RouteCollection);
u.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["borrowerId"] = -999;
// Recreate the exact same URL with the changed borrowerId

I cannot use string replace, as some of the other values on the URL may be the same as the borrowerId.

Comment: Use DataTokens on a Route to supply extra "metadata" that only applies to your code. Routing will ignore data tokens, but will pass it along so your code can interpret it.