# Extending the RouteCollection in ASP.NET Routing

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, routes

I have been developing a pure MVC CMS for fun and have run into an annoying bug/feature of ASP.NET routing.

Each *dynamic* managed page in my CMS is associated with a particular route that is pulled from the database. These are loaded at app start. When a user adds a new page or edits the Url of an existing page I need to be able to edit the RouteTable to insert/edit route accordingly.

The problem is that the new route does not need to be simply added to the end of the RouteCollection, instead it may need to be inserted into a particular position. Seems logical enough except that the RouteCollection contains only a standard `Insert(int idx, RouteBase route)` method inherited from `Collection<T>` which doesn't contain the route name. The name of the route is important as I use it throughout to generate action links.

Looking at reflector I can't see an easy way to extend this collection as the _namedMap dictionary is marked as private. I tried chopping the collection at the point of insert and re-adding each item again, however because there is no method to reverse lookup a route's name from the RouteCollection I cannot re-add them with the name they may have had before. So frustrating!!!

Why is the name of the route not a property of the route object?
Why if MS is serious about us extending MVC and Routing do they make crucial classes hard to extend?

Any suggestions as to the best solution here?

**Edit :**

Ok maybe I should have been **much much** clearer here. I am not looking for a critique of my CMS design. I appreciate the comments but this is not what I am asking.

Simplified question. How can I insert a named route into the route collection at runtime? The current insert method on the class is insufficient as it does not include the name.

Cheers,

Ian

Comment: Why exactly do you have 1-to-1 mapping of routes to managed pages? You might be able to simplify your URL structure so you can keep reusing the same routes independent of the managed page.

Comment: @Berin: Ah, yes.  I hadn't thought of that. One route per page is indeed a bad design.  Should be using parameter values within an existing route to identify pages.

Comment: I wasn't quite clear, for example I have a managed blog details page with the url of post/{name}/{id} and I don't have to manage the url parsing. I have a catch all at the end of the managed route block that handles simple static urls so it isn't quite one route per page its one route per dynamic page + 1. My problem still stands.

Comment: I did say "managed" page, so I get what you were saying.  Perhaps if you gave an idea of what you want your URLs to look like, I can help you come up with a routes strategy that is a lot simpler.

Comment: Hmm... Short of creating static files (and ensuring that `RouteExistingFiles` is `true`), there's not a nice way of doing what you're asking without forcing an application restart every time some CRUD occurs on a route.

Comment: @Dan Atkinson Theres no need to force an application to restart. I can easily add a route at runtime to the end of the collection. I just can't insert one in the middle without sacrificing the name part.

Comment: You could always copy the routes into a temp collection, run ClearItems() and then re-insert them (including your new route which was added at the required position).

Comment: As mentioned in my answer, `Add()` might be what you need, as it uses the Route name, which you require.

Comment: Yes I could and I tried this but as mentioned, when you copy the items out of the collection you lose the name information. If you have a reference to a particular RouteBase object you have no way to lookup its name in the collection.

Comment: @madcapnmckay, how did you manage to add a route to route collection? I'm trying to do it and I can actually add a route, when I debug my application a see the route in the collection, but it looks like this route is simple ignored by application, it doesn't work even though if the route is correct, when I add it in Global.asax it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a look at the [`ClearItems()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.routing.routecollection.clearitems.aspx) method, this should provide a way to empty out the routes. If you first move your routes collection into a temporary collection (and insert your new route in there as well), run ClearItems() and then re-populate using  [`Add()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc680150.aspx).

It should be mentioned that you should also use the [`GetReadLock()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.routing.routecollection.getreadlock.aspx) and [`GetWriteLock()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.routing.routecollection.getwritelock.aspx) in order to avoid potential conflicts in your application.

Comment: Correct but I would lose the name information of all existing routes by doing that. Because the name info is stored in a private _namedMap dictionary it is not part of the route itself. What is required is an Insert(name, RouteBase route) method.

Comment: Doesn't `RouteData.DataTokens` contain that information that you could simply extract? Further information - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/363211

Answer (score 0):

Look at the `IRouteConstraint` interface. Basically you add a catch all route add the end of the collection at application startup, which takes a constraint object as parameter. In here you would lookup in your CMS if the incoming url matches a valid page and then return true or false, which will instruct the routing framework whether the route should be considered for the incoming request or not

```
public interface IRouteConstraint
{
  bool Match(HttpContextBase httpContext, 
    Route route, 
    string parameterName, 
    RouteValueDictionary values, 
    RouteDirection routeDirection);
}
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.routing.irouteconstraint.aspx

Defines the contract that a class must implement in order to check whether a URL parameter value is valid for a constraint.

Answer (score -2):

Short answer:  you don't insert routes dynamically.  When it's time to change them, they need to be rebuilt from scratch.  There's several reasons for this, most tied to ensuring the routing system is not the bottleneck for your application.  Essentially the set of routes is *intended* to be a small static set of resources that map a large number of URLs.  Everything about the routing system was designed with that in mind.

This is a departure for many developers, particularly coming from file-based frameworks (like routeless WebForms projects).  It does force you to think about the URLs a bit differently.

---

URL Routing was recently made popular by Ruby on Rails, which in turn got the idea from a paper on Representational State Transfer (REST): http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_State_Transfer .  The concept existed prior to Rails, but it is a concept that was carried over to ASP.NET MVC.

The principle behind RESTful routes is that they have a common structure, with only certain portions changing.  In your application, it would be the name of the managed page.  By default, ASP.NET matches your route like this:

```
/{controller}/{action}/{id}
```

This means that the portion of the URL that matches where the "{controller}" word is will be stored in the "controller" parameter.  Same with {action} and {id} as well.  What this means is that you can have common logic for managed pages like this:

```
/Page/Details/I eat spinach
```

That gets mapped as follows:

- controller = "Page" (maps to the PageController class in your Controllers directory)
- action = "Details" (maps to the Details method on the PageController class)
- id = "I eat spinach" (passed as a parameter on the Details action.

Your controller code would have a method like this:

```
public ActionResult Details(string id)
{
    return View(db.FindPage(id));
}
```

With those basics out of the way, we are not limited to this structure.  As long as we have a way of providing a mapping to the right controller, the right action, and can look up the managed page by id, we can make the URL what we want.  Let's say we wanted the page name to come first, and the action to come second, and we didn't want to worry about the controller at all.  We would create a route that looks like this:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "ManagedPages",  // Route Name
    "{id}/{action}", // URL structure
    // Default route parameters
    new { controller = "ManagedPage", action = "Details", id = "Home" }
);
```

The parameters provide default values if they are not overidden in the URL.  That means a blank URL will always match to `ManagedPageController.Details("Home")`.  If you wanted to edit the page, the URL might look like "I eat spinach/Edit".

There are some caveats to the "id" parameter, which relate to forbidden characters the MVC tries to save you from.  If you force the page names to never include these forbidden characters you will have a lot fewer problems.

Comment: Erm. Thanks for the effort but I am well aware how routing works. My question is simply how do you insert a route dynamically into the RouteCollection in ASP.NET routing.

Comment: My answer is that I believe you are making it more complicated than necessary.