# Validating DataTokens in RouteCollection

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I'm extending RouteCollection in a similar way that is mentioned at "[How can I get the route name in controller in ASP.NET MVC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/363211/how-can-i-get-the-route-name-in-controller-in-asp-net-mvc)". By doing so, I'm adding two properties that are optional. For one of the properites that I'm adding, I'd like to verify that the value is within a valid range and is unique in nature. Since DataTokens are a KeyValue Collection, I can only think to check the value in my extension. However, I continually receive an error during a foreach after attempting to GetReadLock() from  the RouteTable. Here's an example:

```
public static Route MapRouteWithProperties(this RouteCollection routes, string name, string url, object defaults, object constraints, bool isDefaultRoute)
{
  Route route = routes.MapRoute(name, url, defaults, constraints);
  route.DataTokens = new RouteValueDictionary();
  route.DataTokens.Add("IsDefaultRoute", isDefaultRoute);

  if (isDefaultRoute)
  {
    if (routes != null && routes.Count > 0)
    {
      RouteCollection tempRoutes = RouteTable.Routes;
      using (tempRoutes.GetReadLock())
      {
        foreach (Route tempRoute in tempRoutes)
        {
          if (bool.Parse(tempRoute.DataTokens["IsDefaultRoute"].ToString()) == true)
          {
            /// TODO Do something.
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }

  return route;
}
```

The error is "Object not set to an instance of an object." which makes me believe that the lock is still on the collection.

**UPDATE:** The error is thrown when enumerating the tempRoutes RouteCollection and occurs exactly at:

```
foreach (Route tempRoute in tempRoutes)
```

Answer (score 0):

The DataTokens collection is initially null when there are no tokens.

Check tempRoute.Datatokens for null before trying to access the key value in the loop at tempRoute.DataTokens["IsDefaultRoute"]

Comment: The error is in the for each Route line and not on the DataTokens line.