# How to get route name from Attribute routing in ASP MVC5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, routes, asp.net-mvc-5, attributerouting

Does anyone know how to get the route name from Attribute routing in a action filter?

For example I have a controller and attribute route like this:

```
[HttpGet]
[CustomActionAttribute]
[Route("~/index", Name="IndexPage")]
public async Task<ActionResult> Index()
{
    //Controller logic
}
```

Is it possible to get route name in the CustomActionAttribute?

```
public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
{
    //Get the current route name here
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I get the route name in controller in ASP.NET MVC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/363211/how-can-i-get-the-route-name-in-controller-in-asp-net-mvc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extend RouteCollection to achieve this. You can find example code for this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/363211/how-can-i-get-the-route-name-in-controller-in-asp-net-mvc)

Comment: But that means I have to have a custom attribute route attribute?

Comment: After poking around the source code, I realized that the route name  mapping is saved in a private field in RouteCollection class
private Dictionary<string, RouteBase> _namedMap = new Dictionary<string, RouteBase>(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
So I don't think we could access it. The only viable way would be create one for our own as you suggest it. Any other ideas?

Comment: From what I have read so far, It seems to be the least painful way.