# How to get route name in htmlhelper?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, routes

I want to get the current route name in my html helper but I don't know how to make it.

I thinks the solution is in this post [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/363211/how-can-i-get-the-route-name-in-controller-in-asp-net-mvc) but I don't know how to create the RouteCollectionExtions.

For the moment my code is:

> ```
> using System;
> using System.Collections.Generic;
> using System.Globalization;
> using System.Linq;
> using System.Web;
> using System.Web.Mvc;
> using System.Web.Routing;
>
> public static class RouteCollectionExtensions
>     {
>         public static Route MapRouteWithName(this RouteCollection routes, string name, string url, object defaults, object constraints)
>         {
>             Route route = routes.MapRoute(name, url, defaults, constraints);
>             route.DataTokens = new RouteValueDictionary();
>             route.DataTokens.Add("RouteName", name);
>
>             return route;
>         }
>     }
>
>     public class RouteConfig
>     {
>         public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollectionExtensions routes)
>         {
>             routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
>             routes.IgnoreRoute("favicon.ico");
>
>             // Default
>             routes.MapRoute ("Default", "", new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional });
>             outes.MapRouteWithName("HomeFr", "fr", new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" });
>         }
>     }
> ```

Do you know why the compiler says:

> 'MyNamespace.RouteCollectionExtensions' does not contain a definition for 'MapRoute' and the best extension method overload 'System.Web.Mvc.RouteCollection.Extensions.MapRoute(System.web.Routing.RouteCollection, string, string, string[])' has some invalid arguments.

Thanks you for your help.
Regards,

Comment: How are you using the MapRouteWithName?

Comment: Thank your for your reply, I've edited the post... Do you know why it doesn't work ?

Comment: Yes, look at my answer below. You should use RouteCollection, not RouteCollectionExtension (in this line -->  public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollectionExtensions routes))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to use the link you suggested, this is how your RouteConfig should look like:

(I dropped the constraints, because I didn't see he's using it in the example)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Routing;
namespace MvcApplication1
{
    public static class RouteCollectionExtensions
    {
        public static Route MapRouteWithName(this RouteCollection routes, string name, string url, object defaults)
        {
            Route route = routes.MapRoute(name, url, defaults);
            route.DataTokens = new RouteValueDictionary();
            route.DataTokens.Add("RouteName", name);

            return route;
        }
    }


    public class RouteConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
            routes.MapRouteWithName(
                "myRouteName",
                "{controller}/{action}/{username}",
                new { controller = "Home", action = "List" }

                );
        }
    }
}
```