# ASP.NET Core - get route from controller type

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, routes

How can I get route from controller type?

for example get route of `MyTestController` & `LoosedController` from kind of service or something else.

`XService.GetRoute<MyTestController>(); // output: /api/x/MyTest`
`XService.GetRoute<LoosedController>(); // output: /api/loosed-items`

```cs
[Route("api/x/[controller]")]
public abstract class MyControllerBase : ControllerBase {
    [HttpGet("{id}")]
    public ActionResult Get(int id) {
        return Ok(id);
    }
}

[Route("api/loosed-items")]
public class LoosedController : MyControllerBase {
}

public class MyTestController : MyControllerBase {
    [HttpGet("action")]
    public ActionResult FindThis() {
        return Ok();
    }
}
```

Comment: check this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/363211/how-can-i-get-the-route-name-in-controller-in-asp-net-mvc

Comment: @SSD i just have controller type, i must take route just with Type.

Comment: You can use reflection logic and retrieve what you want. check this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21583278/getting-all-controllers-and-actions-names-in-c-sharp

Comment: @SSD its not useful, reflaction cant handle routeTemplate and `RouteAttribute` inheritance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your description, you could try to use `IActionDescriptorCollectionProvider` to get all controller routes.

More details, you could refer to below codes:

Interface:

```
public interface IGetRoute
{
    IList<RouteModel> GetRotue(string type);
}
```

Class:
public class GetRoute : IGetRoute
{
private readonly IActionDescriptorCollectionProvider _actionDescriptorCollectionProvider;

```
    public GetRoute(IActionDescriptorCollectionProvider actionDescriptorCollectionProvider)
    {
        _actionDescriptorCollectionProvider = actionDescriptorCollectionProvider;
    }


    public IList<RouteModel> GetRotue(string type)
    {

        var typename = type.Replace("Controller", "");

        List<RouteModel> result = new List<RouteModel>();

        foreach (ActionDescriptor _e in _actionDescriptorCollectionProvider.ActionDescriptors.Items)
        {

            if (_e.AttributeRouteInfo != null)
            {
                if (_e.AttributeRouteInfo.Template.Contains(typename))
                {
                    result.Add(new RouteModel() { Name = _e.AttributeRouteInfo.Template, ControllerName = typename });
                }
            } else if (_e is ControllerActionDescriptor)
            {
                var e = _e as ControllerActionDescriptor;
                if (e.ControllerName == typename)
                {
                    result.Add(new RouteModel() { Name = $"/{e.ControllerName}/{e.ActionName}", ControllerName = typename });
                }

            }


        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

Register in ConfigureServices method:

```
        services.AddScoped<IGetRoute, GetRoute>();
```

Usage:

```
        var res = _route.GetRotue(typeof(MyTestController).Name);

        var res2 = _route.GetRotue(typeof(HomeController).Name);
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: This answer fails to take into account the route template and associated values.